# rotate box by 180 degrees should change background color but fails. Bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("box");
  element.classList.toggle("wendeBox");
}
```

```css
.wendeBox{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: green;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transition: 1.3s;
}

#box{
 transition: 1.3s;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction()'>wenden</button>
<div id='box'>Box 1</div>
```

The code above works in the sense that it does rotate the box and interestingly upon flipping even sets the font color to green, however, it fails to make the box yellow. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. The reason lies with the selectors you used.

If two CSS rules have conflicting properties (in this case, the background color), the rule with the higher specificity wins. In your case, `.wendeBox` is a class selector, while `#box` is an ID selector. ID selectors have higher specificity, so the blue background wins.

To fix your issue, I'd recommend the following:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>wenden</button>
<div id='box'>Box 1</div>

#box{
    transition: 1.3s;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#box.wendeBox {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: green;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here, the `#box.wendeBox` rule has higher specificity than just `.wendeBox`, so it can override the `#box` rule.

I'd suggest you read up on CSS selectors for more details. As a very basic starter, here's a quick list of specificity order:

1. Class/pseudoclass selectors, e.g. `.wendeBox` or `:focus`
2. Tag selectors, e.g. `div`
3. ID selectors, e.g. `#box`
4. Composite selectors (any combination of the above)

If two rules have equal specificity, then the one that was declared later in the CSS source code wins.

Answer (score 1):

Added important to the  `background-color: yellow !important;` since the `#box` already has a background-color value set to blue

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("box");
  element.classList.toggle("wendeBox");
}
```

```css
.wendeBox{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px;
 background-color: yellow !important;
 color: green;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transition: 1.3s;
}

#box{
 transition: 1.3s;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction()'>wenden</button>
<div id='box'>Box 1</div>
```

Comment: The reason this answer is correct is because your background-color style for the id has a higher precedence than the same style for the class. An id selector will always override a class selector. Which is why the !important is necessary, so it raises the precedence of the class property to be used instead of the id.

Comment: @dukedevil294 i totally agree the id always override the class value , but when using !important you can overide the id value

Comment: The suggestion `!important` works. But the font still changes color to green, eventhough it is in the toggled class and with that should be overridden by the ID font color. How can you tell, what elements get which precedence?

Comment: @iBim'sdaMichi set a new font color in the #box and it will overide it

Answer (score 1):

What you've got there is css [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

An id will render over a class. All you need to do is change the css so you reference the id with the class.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("box");
  element.classList.toggle("wendeBox");
}
```

```css
#box.wendeBox{
 background-color: yellow;
 color: green;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#box{
 transition: 1.3s;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction()'>wenden</button>
<div id='box'>Box 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `!important` to the yellow as in `background-color: yellow !important;` so as to impose the yellow color.

But note, it's not always good practise to use `!important`